# Windows 7 RTM to Windows 7 Retail Upgrade

Tags: windows-7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When reinstalling Windows 7 or Vista, does the language, version, architecture (64-bit or 32-bit) or source (OEM, retail, or MSDN) matter?](https://superuser.com/questions/303136/when-reinstalling-windows-7-or-vista-does-the-language-version-architecture-6)

I installed the RTM version of Windows 7 Professional and today I received the upgrade media for Windows 7 Professional. It won't take the serial number because the RTM is the full version, duh. Can I "upgrade" my RTM version and still keep all my settings and programs?

To clarify, the RTM is a full install version and I have the upgrade media. So, no changing the key won't work.

Comment: I'm a little confused why you want to upgeade from windwos 7 pro to windows 7 pro? The RTM version is the same version as you have on your upgrade media.

Comment: Do you just want to change the key?

Comment: You might be able to do something using slmgr but I've not seen any documentation on it, sorry

Answer (score 2):

I am under the impression you can just go into System properties (Right click my computer | properties or winkey + Pause/break) and enter a new key under the Windows activation section. There is an option to "Change Product Key"